# mongodb - use geoNear without omitting non 2dsphere indexed rows

Tags: mongodb

When using geoNear, all rows which do not have location (not a part of 2dsphere index) are omitted.

How to use geoNear to get nearest results but also show other rows that do not have location? The rows which do not have a location should be ranked lower in the results.

```
.collection('users')
.aggregate([
  {             
    $geoNear: {
       near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [userLocArray[0], userLocArray[1]]},
       distanceField: "dist.calculated",
       spherical: true,
       //maxDistance: matchDistance,
    }
  },
```

Example documents (In the example below, the users `xyz` and `mmm` are omitted by `geoNear` because they do not have location field. I just wanted them to be ranked lowest but not completely omitted.

```
   db={
      users: [
        {
          _id: "abc",
          name: "abc",
          group: 1,
          location: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [
              53.23,
              67.12
            ]
          },
          calculatedDist: 112
        },
        {
          _id: "xyz",
          name: "xyyy",
          group: 1,
          calculatedDist: 13
        },
        {
          _id: "123",
          name: "yyy",
          group: 1,
          location: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [
              54.23,
              67.12
            ]
          },
          calculatedDist: 13
        },
        {
          _id: "rrr",
          name: "tttt",
          group: 1,
          location: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [
              51.23,
              64.12
            ]
          },
          calculatedDist: 14
        },
        {
          _id: "mmm",
          name: "mmmm",
          group: 1,
          calculatedDist: 14
        },

      ]
    }
```

Comment: Can you add some sample json documents and the expected output so we can try to replicate the issue?

Comment: @ray - Added example. mongoplayground does not do geoNear because there is no 2dsphere index otherwise I would have created a sample playground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add another `$match` stage at the end of pipeline to choose those documents without location

```js
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$geoNear": {
      "near": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          53.23,
          67.12
        ]
      },
      "distanceField": "d"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "users",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "location": null
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Yes, you are right that Mongo Playground cannot demonstrate 2d sphere index behaviour. But I put [it](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PHgPIoX82tK) here nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks.  thats worked. I will probably create a separate question but would there be a reason why maxDistance works on local mongodb but not on prod? same code, same 2dsphere index but as soon as I use maxDistance, no results in prod.

Comment: `mgodatagen` approach allows you to specify the index and demonstrate the full approach, [playground here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zbtv2-lF-rN). If somebody knows of a way to provide an `enum` of the full document let me know...

Comment: @user20042973 wow! Never know Playground can do something like that :D

Comment: I didn't either, [@rickhg12hs taught me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74018094/mongodb-index-based-text-searches-to-match-full-string/74033836#comment130721664_74033836) a few weeks ago. Pretty nifty

Comment: New question sounds reasonable @Kal - but did you double check that the data itself is the same? There's also a note about what unit that parameter is expressed in depending on the type of data that is indexed if I recall correctly